# What does python sys getsizeof for string return?

Tags: python

What does `sys.getsizeof` return for a standard string? I am noticing that this value is much higher than what `len` returns.

Comment: Did you trying reading the documentation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I will attempt to answer your question from a broader point of view. You're referring to two functions and comparing their outputs. Let's take a look at their documentation first:

- [len()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len):

> Return the length (the number of items) of an object. The argument may
>   be a sequence (such as a string, bytes, tuple, list, or range) or a
>   collection (such as a dictionary, set, or frozen set).

So in case of string, you can expect `len()` to return the number of characters.

- [sys.getsizeof()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof):

> Return the size of an object in bytes. The object can be any type of
>   object. All built-in objects will return correct results, but this
>   does not have to hold true for third-party extensions as it is
>   implementation specific.

So in case of string (as with many other objects) you can expect `sys.getsizeof()` the size of the object in bytes. There is no reason to think that it should be the same as the number of characters.

Let's have a look at some examples:

```
>>> first = "First"
>>> len(first)
5
>>> sys.getsizeof(first)
42
```

This example confirms that the size is not the same as the number of characters.

```
>>> second = "Second"
>>> len(second)
6
>>> sys.getsizeof(second)
43
```

We can notice that if we look at a string one character longer, its size is one byte bigger as well. We don't know if it's a coincidence or not though.

```
>>> together = first + second
>>> print(together)
FirstSecond
>>> len(together)
11
```

If we concatenate the two strings, their combined length is equal to the sum of their lengths, which makes sense.

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(together)
48
```

Contrary to what someone might expect though, the size of the combined string is not equal to the sum of their individual sizes. But it still seems to be the length plus *something*. In particular, *something* worth 37 bytes. Now you need to realize that it's 37 bytes in this particular case, using this particular Python implementation etc. You should not rely on that at all. Still, we can take a look why it's 37 bytes what they are (approximately) used for.

String objects are in CPython (probably the most widely used implementation of Python) implemented as `PyStringObject`. This is the C [source code](https://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.9/file/753a8f457ddc/Include/stringobject.h#l35) (I use the 2.7.9 version):

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    long ob_shash;
    int ob_sstate;
    char ob_sval[1];

    /* Invariants:
     *     ob_sval contains space for 'ob_size+1' elements.
     *     ob_sval[ob_size] == 0.
     *     ob_shash is the hash of the string or -1 if not computed yet.
     *     ob_sstate != 0 iff the string object is in stringobject.c's
     *       'interned' dictionary; in this case the two references
     *       from 'interned' to this object are *not counted* in ob_refcnt.
     */
} PyStringObject;
```

You can see that there is something called `PyObject_VAR_HEAD`, one `int`, one `long` and a `char` array. The char array will always contain one more character to store the `'\0'` at the end of the string. This, along with the `int`, `long` and `PyObject_VAR_HEAD` take the additional 37 bytes. `PyObject_VAR_HEAD` is defined in [another C source file](https://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.9/file/753a8f457ddc/Include/object.h#l90) and it refers to other implementation-specific stuff, you need to explore if you want to find out where exactly are the 37 bytes. Plus, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) mentions that `sys.getsizeof()`

> adds an additional garbage collector overhead if the object is managed
>   by the garbage collector.

Overall, you don't need to know what exactly takes the *something* (the 37 bytes here) but this answer should give you a certain idea why the numbers differ and where to find more information should you really need it.

Comment: To be clear, the "additional garbage collector overhead" doesn't apply to `str` on CPython. That extra overhead applies for object tracked by CPython's cyclic garbage collector, and "leaf types" (objects which cannot contain references to other objects, and therefore cannot be a link in a cyclic reference chain, like `str`, `bytes`, `int`, `float`, etc.) don't need the extra GC linkages used to enable cyclic garbage collection. By contrast, all the collection types without single uniform data stored (`list`, `tuple`, `set`, `dict`, user-defined classes, etc.) do pay for that overhead.

Answer (score 2):

To quote the documentation:

> Return the size of an object in bytes. The object can be any type of object. All built-in objects will return correct results, but this does not have to hold true for third-party extensions as it is implementation specific.

Built in strings are not simple character sequences - they are full fledged objects, with garbage collection overhead, which probably explains the size discrepancy you're noticing.