# How Python manage memory for variable converting

Tags: python, interpreter

I am intersted in learning programming languages and interpreters implementation. I want to know how exactly Python manages memory like when you declare a string variable:

```
Num = "12"
```

I think this variable will take 2 bytes in memory then when you convert it to int`Num = int(Num)` it will take 4 bytes how Python will manage to reserve 4 bytes for that int and don't override the next variable ?

Comment: Python doesn't really have variables in the sense that you seem to be thinking of.

Comment: "I think this variable will take 2 bytes in memory then when you convert it to intNum = int(Num) it will take 4 bytes" I cannot emphasize enough how flawed these statements are. This is actually 3 questions disguised as one.

Comment: You want to know? Take a look [hg.python.org/cpython](https://hg.python.org/cpython/) .

Comment: For more in-depth reading about what the overhead of each object might be, read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30255307/what-does-python-sys-getsizeof-for-string-return).