# Why does empty string show a size of 49 in python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, memory

```
import sys
s = ""
print(sys.getsizeof(s))
```

output : 49

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does python sys getsizeof for string return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30255307/what-does-python-sys-getsizeof-for-string-return)

Answer (score 2):

Because strings in Python are a certain type of object, they are not just a collection of enough characters to hold the string. As per the Python documentation, `sys.getsizeof()` will ...

> Return the size of an ***object*** in bytes.

The size of the object may be larger for a variety of reasons, such as holding extra space for expansion without re-allocation, or having a minimum size. See, for example, [`PEP393`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/) introduced in Python 3.3, which shows several (verbose) structures.

If you want the *length* of the string rather than the size of the internal object, I'm *sure* there's a function for that. Maybe it's called `len()` :-)